# Return all files excepts .txt

Tags: powershell, foreach, where-clause

I want all files except the ones that ends on .txt.

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $Out | Where $file.Extension -ne .txt) {

Write-Host $file.name

}
```

This lists all the items in the directory including .txt.

What should this really look like?

Comment: Which language is this? Some kind of shell script? You should add it to the question and probably tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a loop to do this, just:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Extension -ne ".txt" } Select-Object "Name"
```

Or:

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude "*.txt" | Select-Object "Name"
```

---

If you insist on a loop, or need it for something, you can:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Exclude "*.txt") { Write-Host $file.Name; }
```

or

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Extension -ne ".txt" }) { Write-Host $file.Name; }
```

or

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem | Where-Object Extension -ne ".txt") { Write-Host $file.Name; }
```

The example from the question does not work because `$file` is only available *inside* the `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you. It works. But do you have any idea why my code does not work?

Comment: If you use a `Where` you need to write your conditions slighlty different. Check [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849715.aspx) for all the options.

Comment: @user3019059 yours doesn't work because `$file` does not exist until the foreach code block inside the braces `{}`. You can't use `$file.Extension` before that, in the foreach iteration bit. It would have to be `foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem $Out | Where Extension -ne '.txt' )) { ... }`